# Laravel cashier + Stripe : creating a plan with quantity and decreasing prices

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-5.4, laravel-cashier

I'm whiling for one of my project to create a subscription system with Laravel Cashier and Stripe.

We will offer one plan to our users : 10€ / month for one location (they can add locations in the system) and for 75 followers.

What I want to do, is to make them pay more for locations : 2.5€ / locations / month for example, so this can be achieve with quantities ? But still, if the basic plan is at 10€ and I put 2 as a quantity, total price will be 20€ ?

Then price will be also based on their followers. 75 are included in the basic price. But then if they want more, they will also have to pay.

Example :

- 76-150 : + 4.95€ a month
- 151-250 : + 4.80€ a month etc ...

How can I handle that and make sure the customer will have to pay everything in one shot ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to;

1. Calculate the total charge in your own logic,
2. Initiate a 'once-off' payment by first creating a customer object,
3. Then creating a charge!

---

Easy as 1,2,3 :D

Here's a tutorial from Stripes documentation on creating payments.
https://stripe.com/docs/charges

---

If you would like to add the user to a plan (subscription), see the below example (in PHP).

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
   "source" => $tokenID, 
   "plan" => $plan,
   "email" => $email,
   "coupon" => $coupon
));
```

Comment: This is indeed a good idea, but charges are paid in one-shoot right ? 
Is there any way I can transform a charge, into a subcription ? Because in the end they will need to pay that every month.

I can also do "multiple subcriptions", one to handle locations, and the other one to handle the followers ? 
But cashier does not support that feature.

Comment: Yes you can indeed create multiple subscriptions! All you have to do is specify the plan in the charge. Note: you will have to handle when to end those subscriptions as well as update them via webhooks when for example the user does not pay. Check my updated answer for some source code!

Answer (score 0):

I would use my front or back end to calculate:

- price
- discount rate

When the calculation is done, you can create your subscription with the right quantity and price, and discount rate (discount coupon).

```
$user->newSubscription('main', 'main')
    ->quantity($quantity)
    ->withCoupon($coupon)
    ->create($token, ['email' => $user->email]);
```